# Convert Key Value pairs to Json

Tags: python, graphql

I am trying to use certain data that I have received from database as below format after coded like below in Python :

```
('ACTION_CODE', 'S')
('ARRIVAL_DATE', '03-JUL-19')
('BIT_FLAGS', '1082131456')
('CONFIG_DATA_SOURCE', 'SPT')
```

I have used below code to get above results :

```
print("Object length :", len(rv.value.items()))   #rv is database row and I am iterating across database columns for one row 
for k, v in (rv.value.items()):  # Iterate over the key value pairs
    kv = k, v
    print((kv))
```

I want to get the data kv in JSON format to use json.dumps(kv) ... where kv is acceptable format for json.dumps function . How can I write the code to get kv ? 
any help please

Also mentioning that I am feeding this data back to GraphQL so I have little bit restricted with my schema definition ...

final goal is to use json2obj(json.dumps(kv)) :

```
def _json_object_hook(d):
    return namedtuple("X", d.keys())(*d.values())


def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)
```

Comment: Can you please also add the print of rv.value ?

Comment: Declare and populate a `dict` data structure in the for loop. Then use this `dict` to generate json using `json.dumps(dict)` outside the for loop.

Comment: print (rv.value) return below : {'ACTION_CODE': 'S', 'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19', 'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456', 'CONFIG_DATA_SOURCE': 'SPT'}

Comment: `rv.value` is a dictionary, you can just do `json.dumps(rv.value)`

Comment: can't use json.dumps(rv.value) as I have to get a lists which is returned a named tuple from json2obj function . .Sorry I have edited that later

Comment: Please just provide which is your desired output clearly (example output as string, just to be precise)

Answer (score 1):

Without more data I am a bit coding in the darkness but this is what I suggest:

```
result = {}

for k, v in rv.value.items():
    result[k] = v

json_data = json.dumps(result)
print(json_data)
```

Edit:
Since now I see in your comments that rv.value already contains a dictionary the conversion is as easy as:

```
#rv.value.items = {'ACTION_CODE': 'S', 'ARRIVAL_DATE': '03-JUL-19', 'BIT_FLAGS': '1082131456', 'CONFIG_DATA_SOURCE': 'SPT'}
result = []
for key, value in rv.value.items():
    result.append({key : value})
print(result)
# Then the JSON conversion will be simple
json_data = json.dumps(result)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: hey @Pitto .. json.dumps(rv.value) is already giving me that as {"ACTION_CODE": "S", "ARRIVAL_DATE": "03-JUL-19", "BIT_FLAGS": "1082131456" } ... I guess I want this as list of dictionaries like below for GraphQL to return appropriately  : [ {"ACTION_CODE": "S"}, {"ARRIVAL_DATE": "03-JUL-19"} , {"BIT_FLAGS": "1082131456" } ]

Comment: @pauldx I' ve understood your requirement, I am now updating the code

Answer (score 0):

Declare this before the for loop

```
dict = {}
```

In the for loop add key-value pairs to the dict

```
dict[key] = value
```

After the for loop dump it

```
json.dumps(dict)
import json
dict = {}
dict['a'] = 'b'
dict['c'] = 'd'
json.dumps(dict)
```

Output: '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'

**Edit**: Based on the required output format here is the code:

```
import json
dict1 = {'a':'b'}
dict2 = {'c':'d'}
result=[]
result.append(dict1)
result.append(dict2)
print(json.dumps(result))

Output: [{"a": "b"}, {"c": "d"}]
```

Comment: json.dumps(rv.value) is already giving me that ... I guess I want this as list of dictionaries like below :   [
    {"ACTION_CODE": "S"},
    {"ARRIVAL_DATE": "03-JUL-19"} ,
   {"BIT_FLAGS": "1082131456" }                    
]

Comment: Added code above. Use a list where dictionaries are added and dump the list.